# C++ threading: first come mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I am trying to solve the following architecture, but having some trouble.

Basically there are multiple threads accessing the same the same object in parallel. The first thread is meant to execute `Object.A()` and all the other threads are supposed to wait until that process is finished and then proceed to execute `Object.B()` simultaneously without any blocking.

Can't find any resources online that explain anything would produce this functionality and any "solution" that jumps to mind with 2 custom boolean mutexes doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Why not just call `Object.A()` in the main thread and then spin up all of the other threads to call `B()`?

Comment: why are people upvoting this? if this was a possibility in my actual code i would have done so.

Comment: Okay then why not use a condition variable?  The thread that calls `Object.A()` sets a condition variable to true after `A()` finishes and then all the other threads wait for the notification before the proceed?

Comment: @user2255757 It is unreasonable for you to expect anybody reading this to know anything at all about what is and isn't a possibility in your actual code, so you will have to take all suggestions as helpful with good intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach NathanOliver suggested in the comments, to call `A()` on the main thread and *then* spin up the other threads, is the simplest approach and the first one you should consider.

But the construct you are looking for is called a "[monitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization))" (the piece you are missing is called a "condition variable", "monitor" refers to the whole mutex + cond var pair that you'll need).

I'm not going to reproduce examples here since it's pretty easy to find info ([Travis Gockel just posted a nice example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38445322/616460)). Depending on your threading subsystem:

- For pthreads see [condition variables](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/6je9h032r/index.html).
- For the Windows API see both [Condition Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682052(v=vs.85).aspx) as well as [Event Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682655(v=vs.85).aspx), both can be used to accomplish similar things, I kinda prefer the latter when applicable for basic boolean condition variables except resetting the event can get tricky if you have multiple threads waiting and want to wake them all.

The general model, for a one-time run, is:

- First thread:

  - Call `A()`
  - When that returns, signal some "AFinished" cond var.
- Other threads:

  - Wait on "AFinished".
  - Call `B()`

If you want to repeat that process you'll have to reset the condition after all `B()`s are run and wait on that state before calling `A()` again. You could use another cond var to do this, you can do it with a semaphore and some care, etc.

I know this is brief, but hopefully it at least gives you some keywords to search for.

Helpful additional reading:

- https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/locks-mutexes-semaphores.html
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686364(v=vs.85).aspx
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(computer_science)#Synchronization_examples

Alternatively take a look at thread pools with a task queue. You could queue a task that runs `A()` and then enqueues a bunch of `B()` tasks when it is complete (optionally having those `B()` tasks maintain a shared semaphore or just a basic thread-safe counter -- [`InterlockedDecrement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683580(v=vs.85).aspx) and a `volatile` counter on Windows can make this super simple -- monitoring their progress, so the last one can requeue an `A()` runner and repeat).

Answer (score 2):

I am not going into the implementation details but in terms of approach, what you are looking for is a Barrier solution from the [The little book of semaphores](http://greenteapress.com/semaphores/LittleBookOfSemaphores.pdf).

[image: Barrier psuedo code]

***Barrier problem*** is to make all the threads meet at a **rendezvous** point and then all proceed to execute the **critical section(In your case Object.B())**. Before meeting at the **rendezvous** point only first thread executes the Object.A() and join the threads at rendezvous. Look at Reader's writers problem in the same book to get an idea on how to make the first thread execute/call Object.A()

Comment: yea i decided to go with that, but making the rendezvous atomic is becoming problematic since I have to figure out a CUDA solution

Answer (score 1):

If you want it parallel way, use conditial variable to start threads for Object.B(). But Object.B() must be thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using C++11 (or later), this can be done with `std::mutex`, `std::condition_variable` and a `bool`. A quick bit of example code...

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>

class Object
{
public:
    Object() :
        ready(false)
    { }

    void A()
    {
        // do preparation work here

        // Then, you set ready to true and notify all potential waiters in B:
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(protect);
        ready = true;
        ready_cond.notify_all();
    }

    void B()
    {
        if (!ready)
        {
            // Only go into blocking if A isn't done yet
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(protect);
            while (!ready)
                ready_cond.wait(lock);
        }

        // do shared work at this point
    }

private:
    std::mutex              protect;
    bool                    ready;
    std::condition_variable ready_cond;
};
```

This doesn't protect you from multiple people calling `A`, calling again or any number of things that could happen, but it's a starting point.